# Question about CC

Tags: call-options

I think I'm confused about parts of the CC process.  If you're feeling charitable please help a brother out.

My understanding:
I buy 100 shares of ABC @ $25 (5 days duration)
Sell 1 CC contract of ABC @ $28 for premium of $2

I earn $200 premium plus any gains if price approaches $28, great.

The CC's I'm looking at buying only have worthwhile premiums that are **below** the stock price.  How does this work?

My understanding:
100 shares of ABC @ $25 (5 days duration)
Sell 1 CC contract of ABC @ $22 for premium of $1

Does this mean I just get my $100 premium and the brokerage calls my option so I settle 100 shares of ABC @ $22...meaning I'm actually DOWN $200 after the premium fails to offset loss in capital from original purchase price??

***I tried reading other threads on this but couldn't find this specific question.  Please help XD

Comment: What you're describing doesn't sound correct, so actual ticker would be useful in providing an answer.

Comment: "*I buy 100 shares of ABC @ $25 (5 days duration) Sell 1 CC contract of ABC @ $28 for premium of $2*" A 5 day contract 12% out of the money is worth less than a cent, not $2. Are there maybe $2 fees, and strike $28 is actually $0.01-$2=-$2 negative premium, and strike $22 has $3-$2 fee=$1 premium?